How to Securely Implement Password Reset Functionality in Apex to Avoid Unauthorized Access?
I am using Snyk to check my Apex code for any vulnerabilities. When I scanned the system, I got the following output:
User input from a SOQL statement flows into resetPassword. This may allow unauthorized users to reset a password. Avoid exposing this functionality to the user.
My current Apex code is as follows:
`@AuraEnabled
public static String resetPassword(String userName, Boolean isInternal) {        
 FAEXCommunityController.ReturnWrapper returnWrapper = new FAEXCommunityController.ReturnWrapper();
 try {
     // Ensure the method is called by an authorized user
     if (!isCurrentUserAuthorized()) {
         returnWrapper.returnValue = false;
         returnWrapper.errorMessage = 'Unauthorized user.';
         return JSON.serialize(returnWrapper);
     }

     // Validate the input to prevent SOQL injection
     if (String.isBlank(userName) || !Pattern.matches('^[a-zA-Z0-9.@-]+$', userName) && Site.isValidUsername(userName)) {
         returnWrapper.returnValue = false;
         returnWrapper.errorMessage = 'Invalid username format.';
         return JSON.serialize(returnWrapper);
     }
     
     // Query the user to be reset
     User u = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Username, Profile.Name 
               FROM User 
               WHERE Username = :userName 
               AND ContactId != null 
               WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED 
               LIMIT 1];

     // Ensure that only authorized users can call this method
     if (u != null && Site.isValidUsername(u.Username)) {
         **return FAEXUserSettingHelper.resetPassword(u.Id, isInternal);**
     } else {
         returnWrapper.returnValue = false;
         returnWrapper.errorMessage = 'User not found or invalid username.';
     }
 } catch (Exception e) {
     FAEXCommunityController.ErrorHandler errHandler = new FAEXCommunityController.ErrorHandler(e);
     returnWrapper.isError = true;
     returnWrapper.errorMessage = errHandler.makeFriendly();
 }
 return JSON.serialize(returnWrapper);
}`

// Method to check if the current user is authorized to reset passwords
`private static Boolean isCurrentUserAuthorized() {
    try {
        User currentUser = [SELECT Profile.Name, 
                                   (SELECT PermissionSet.Name FROM PermissionSetAssignments) 
                            FROM User 
                            WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() 
                            LIMIT 1];
        
        // Check for authorized profile
        if (currentUser.Profile.Name == 'FAEX Community Login') {
            return true;
        }
        
        // Check for specific permission set
        for (PermissionSetAssignment psa : currentUser.PermissionSetAssignments) {
            if (psa.PermissionSet.Name == 'FA_Ex_Admin') {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log the exception
        System.debug('Authorization check failed: ' + e.getMessage());
    }
    
    return false;
 }
` 

Concerns:

How can I ensure that only authorized users can call this method to reset passwords?
Is my current input validation and security enforced query sufficient to prevent unauthorized access and SOQL injection?
Are there any additional best practices I should follow to secure this functionality?
Any guidance on improving the security of this code would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have implemented a method to check if the current user is authorized to reset passwords by verifying the user's profile and permission sets. I also used String.escapeSingleQuotes to prevent SOQL injection and added a regex pattern to validate the username format.
I expected these measures to prevent unauthorized users from resetting passwords and to avoid any vulnerabilities related to SOQL injection. However, the Snyk scan still flags this as a potential issue, and I want to ensure that my implementation is secure and follows best practices.
Any guidance on improving the security of this code would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
